# Подскажите проекты для начинающих на javascript?

Tags: javascript

Прошла все темы по джава скрипт , умею верстать, но писать сама ничего не умею. Нужна практика! Помогите, могу сделать что то бесплатно под руководством

Comment: Ну так что вам мешает найти задания для простеньких программ в интернете? Если где-то застопоритесь, гуглите и учитесь. В современном мире обязательно нужно уметь быстро осваивать новые сферы.

Comment: Язык программирования не нужно учить как стихи, его нужно понимать. И само программирование, в целом (что это, какие задачи решает). С этим пониманием - придет и осознание того как/где применять. Программиста делает его *мышление*, а не механический набор крутых словечек в текстовом редакторе.

Comment: @yar85 можно вашу почту для связи?

Comment: @VerNicksaysReinstateMonica можно вашу почту для связи?

Comment: @ofelia, Сорри, нет (нахожусь тут только ради знаний, вопросов и ответов... и не заинтересован в переписке).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Несколько идей для практики:

- Генератор случайных цитат
- Калькулятор с кнопками
- Игра "отгадай число"
- Крестики-нолики
- Валидатор номера телефона (чтобы пользователь вводил "89876543210", а в input автоматически срабатывала маска: "+7 (987) 654-32-10")

Ну и почему бы, в конце концов, просто не погуглить "проекты на javascript для начинающих" и начать с самого, на первый взгляд, простого?